# Detect Tab changes inside the detail view of an Object in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, onchange

I have a detail view with system created tabs (created in the page layout) and one of my tabs contains some lightning components that need variables changed when the user moves to another tab.

Currently, I have not found an API or workaround for finding out when the user changes tab to "Detail" or "Related". 
I have tried almost all of the lightning system events and none seem to fire for this event.

Is there a recommended way of detecting these tab changes?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too late, but I have answered a similar question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223948/manually-change-defualt-subtab-on-lightning-app-page/223994#223994).

Pasting the same response in case the link goes down:

You are out of luck (at least at the time of writing this answer). All the standard lightning components (unless documented otherwise) do not contain events/attributes you can interact with publicly, they are kind of little black boxes. So you must resort to creating a custom component to accomplish your objective.